# Integrate Open Policy Agent to .Net Core APIs

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, open-policy-agent

I read a lot about Open Policy Agent OPA (www.openpolicyagent.org) and found it is a great way to policy-based control for HTTP API authorization.

I am wondering whether Microsoft has any plan to integrate this to the new .NET Core.

Comment: Sorry, general software/tool questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on the OPA Slack: https://slack.openpolicyagent.org/